# Optimize select by multiple group by and sub queries

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery

I'm trying to select all orders by:

1. Select all addresses (by using post code and street address) that have more than 1 order;
2. Select all those orders.

My current query looks like this:

```
SELECT  o.*
FROM    ( SELECT o2.orders_id
              FROM `zen_orders` o2
              GROUP BY delivery_postcode, delivery_street_address
              HAVING COUNT(o2.orders_id) > 1
        ) AS o3
LEFT JOIN zen_orders AS o ON (o.orders_id = o3.orders_id)
ORDER BY delivery_street_address
```

The query is extremely slow and I wonder what I'm doing wrong and how should I fix it.

Edit: added the index as requested, much much faster. Also ran "explain":

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndHnC.png

Comment: yes orders_id is the primary key

Comment: try adding index on these fields: `delivery_postcode`,  `delivery_street_address`

Comment: Run your query with EXPLAIN and post the results.

Comment: Hi, I added indexes to the 2 fields, look like things are much more faster now. I also ran with "explain" and posted result on the post.

Comment: Why do you need a *left* join?  Any chances not to find an id you've just found in o3?